# Why don't I get output for this DBI/MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, activeperl

I have written the following code in Perl. I have ActivePerl 5.14 for Windows 7.

```
#!C:\perl64\bin\perl.exe -wT
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

# MYSQL CONFIG VARIABLES
my $driver     = "mysql";
my $database   = "test555";
my $tablename3 = "test77";

my $user = "root";
my $pw   = "root";

# PERL MYSQL CONNECT()
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:$driver:$database", $user, $pw,);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT *
          FROM t6
         WHERE paragraph='PWE1234'
    ");

$sth->execute();
#$dbh->disconnect;
#exit 0;
```

When the program reaches `$dbh->disconnect`, the system is throwing an error; hence commented it out. When I comment that out, the system is not throwing any error, but neither do I get output.

There is a result for this query, I checked with MySQL once separately.

Comment: You're not printing anything, why do you expect any output?

Comment: "the system is throwing an error"... What error?

Comment: @gpojd, it was throwing an error reg. statement handle was not closed. Since I used Strict, it was throwing up. So, I gave a finish statement for the statement handle, before closing the database handle.Now resolved!

Comment: @Mannii88, it sounds like you aren't getting all the records before you close the statement handle. That may be by design, but I don't know. I usually `while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow) {...}` to get all the rows and then I don't need to `$sth->finish`.

Comment: @gpojd, can you please give an example with latest module in mind... I am trying parallely with resources from net...I am trying with hashes..I want to print the array...with headers...

Comment: i am able to print through, while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "@row\n"; but, if i want to use 'for' statement, how to get the row count and give the looping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no output because you have no code to create any output.

After calling `execute` you need to call one of the [`fetch`something methods](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref) and do something with the data structure you get back.

Comment: hi @quentin, can you please provide an example or link, where i can find a live example...for fetching array/hashes and printing them in perl..

Comment: i am able to print through, while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "@row\n"; but, if i want to use for statement, how to get the row count and give the looping...

Comment: I doubt you'll find many (if any) DBDs that tell you the row count of the selected rows until you have actually fetched them all and in the case it hardly matters. You can use fetchall_arrayref/fetchall_hashref to get all the rows in a result-set but obviously you'll need the memory to hold them. You can use MaxRows with those methods to limit the rows returned with each call. There are some good examples in the DBI docs.

Comment: `$sth->rows()` would return the number of selected rows.